# How Sip or HTTP Listener works in Java

Tags: java, protocols, listener

I came across a SIP API the other day. What I do not understand is, why I only need to implement the API's listener interface to handle the SIP message? For ex:

```
public void onReInviteSuccessResponse(InviteAgent invite, int code,
            String reason, String body, Message msg);

public void onReInviteFailureResponse(InviteAgent invite, int code,
            String reason, Message msg);
```

I would be glad if anyone can tell me how the code knows when SIP or HTTP messages are actually received?